# Invoking a command at a specific page number

Tags: macros, page-numbering

As with most strange requests on TeX.SE, I too am writing a thesis (with the `book` class). Our department has a hard limit on the amount of pages it can stretch for (70).

For short documents in the past, I used to include a TeX snippet in my preamble that would just drop all pages after a specified amount. However, knowing myself, this could be too "silent" to be reminded of it. One solution I had thought of was invoking `\color{red}` at the start of page 71, so that it jumps out when scrolling through the text. But how do you invoke a command at a specified page number?

Another possibility is using the `xwatermark` package somehow, because I'm already using it to watermark my drafts.

For extra credit: I don't think appendices count towards the total, so a way to automatically determine either 1. the end of the Arabic page numbering or 2. the start of the appendices could be nice too. (You could just put `\color{black}` before `\begin{appendices}`, but having that done automatically in the preamble seems cleaner to me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe making the whole background of the page red will catch your attention when scrolling. For that you can use the `shipout` hook and make the `pagecolor` red

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{
    \ifnum\ReadonlyShipoutCounter=3
        \pagecolor{red}
    \else
        \relax
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\chapter{Who are you?}
Test\newpage
Test2\newpage
\end{document}
```

The result looks something like this

[image]

Comment: Is there a way this can tolerate the offset caused by `\frontmatter`? Currently the 4th page is red, but I would like page 4 to be red, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily (or at all) change the formatting on a specific page, the text that lands on page 71 may have been typeset when only 10 pages have been made (if it had a long paragraph, or if lots of floats were inserted or...) You can not re-set (or even access) that text in classic tex. (luatex changes the rules a bit).

However the current page number can be reliably accessed in the page head, so using `fancyhdr` or directly you could have a page head containing

```
\ifnum\value{page}>70 \textcolor{red}{BAD PAGE}\fi
```

Or you may prefer an error

```
\ifnum\value{page}>70 \PackageError{mythesis}{BAD PAGE}{write less stuff}\fi
```